# Is it only me or matlab's periodogram's function is confusing?

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, dbfs

I am really confused with matlab's periodogram.

First of all, it says in the documentation that its unit is "dB per unit frequency". What does that really mean? I just don't quite get it.

Second of all, I'm trying to evaluate an ADC. I tried to measure its linearity but that won't work because when I reduce the level of the input signal by ,let's say, -3dB I excpect to see -3dB reduction in the highest peak of the spectrum, but that's not the case.

Last but not least, with this "dB per unit frequency" when is the highest peak actually 0 dB? It should reach that at a point, right? Because as far as I know dB is always a ratio of some kind. How can I modify it as to give me the values in dBFs for example? so I could get a sense of what my data look like.

Sorry for the long post, Mathworks' Periodogram just doesn't say it clear.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html) states, `periodogram` provides a *power spectral density* estimate `pxx`:

```
[pxx, w] = periodogram(x);
```

meaning that it shows how the total variance of the signal, `var(x)`, is [distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Properties_of_the_power_spectral_density) over the frequency `w`. This implies that the integral of the estimated spectral density over the frequency axis

```
trapz(w, pxx)
```

should correspond to that total variance.

This also means that the psd is not normalized, neither to a total variance of 1, nor to a maximum peak of 1 (= 0 dB). That the result is plotted (not computed!) in dB merely means that the vertical axis shows $10 \, \log_{10}($ `pxx` $)$, not that it shows a ratio. There is therefore no reason to expect a peak to align with 0 dB; depending on the range of values of the signal it can be both much higher and much lower.

To produce a plot from `pxx` and `w`, use

```
plot(w, 10 * log10(pxx))
xlabel('normalized frequency   [rad / sample]')
ylabel('power spectral density   [(rad/sample)^{-1}] in dB')
```

Reducing the level of the total signal by 3 dB means to divide the signal `x` by a factor of 2. If you do this numerically

```
periodogram(x)
hold all
periodogram(x / 2)
```

you will see that the second psd estimate has exactly the same shape as the first, it's just 3 dB lower. If this is not what you find with your measurement data, then this means that either your volume regulation or your ADC do not work correctly.

---

If you are really sure you want a normalized spectrum, do the following: First, compute the psd estimate:

```
[pxx, w] = periodogram(x);
```

Then, normalize the psd, e.g. with respect to the highest peak:

```
npxx = pxx / max(pxx);
```

You can then plot the *normalized psd* on a logarithmic scale like this:

```
plot(w, 10 * log10(npxx))
xlabel('normalized frequency   [rad / sample]')
ylabel('normalized power spectral density')
```

Note that `npxx` does not have a unit.

---

A note about units: The unit of numbers returned as `pxx` by `periodogram` & friends depends on the units of the input signal  `x`. Let's say these are dimensionless numbers; then the unit of the numbers in the `pxx` output is $\rm \frac{1}{rad / sample}$, because it is a density over `w` which is in units of $\rm rad / sample$. Or let's say these are voltage measurements coming from a calibrated ADC, so that the numbers in `x` are in volts. Then the unit of the numbers in the `pxx` output is $\rm \frac{V^2}{rad / sample}$.

If you additionally specify the sampling frequency in the call to periodogram:

```
[pxx, f] = periodogram(x, [], [], fs);
```

and `fs` is in Hz, the `pxx` is a density over frequency `f`, and its unit is $\rm \frac{V^2}{Hz}$.

Now if `pxx` is plotted, it is often plotted logarithmically, like stated above. If the function $10 \log_{10}$ is used, then it is said that the result is in decibel, dB. Then sometimes the unit of `10 * log10(pxx)` is written as $\rm \frac{dB}{rad / sample}$. Strictly speaking, this expression doesn't make sense because dB is not just a unit (a different measurement stick) but denotes the use of a different quantity: the logarithm. That's why above I wrote the unit as `[(rad/sample)^{-1}] in dB`.

Comment: Okay thanks mate, that explains so much. So if it doesn't compute the power spectral density, to calculate it using FFT is a better approach to get the spectrum, am I right? And that way I could normalize to my ADC levels to show result relative to fullscale.
Thank you again for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @Kevin.hammet, you're welcome, but I get the feeling I wasn't completely clear. `periodogram´ *does* compute the power spectral density. It's just that the psd does not have the properties that you thought it had; you seem to think that the psd is normalized, but it isn't. And if you want to see the effect of reduced volume, that's a good thing: you don't want a normalized psd. I added a section about how to normalize.

Comment: In any case, do not compute the psd using the Fourier transform; those functions in Matlab are there exactly because it is not completely simple, and they take care of the important details. As a matter of fact, it would be even better if you use `pwelch` instead of `periodogram`.

Comment: Thank you for recorrecting the concept, and for suggesting a way to normalize it with respect to its highest peak. No I just want to get this strraight what is the units produced by the periodogram ( or Pwelch) method ? (vrms)^2

Comment: @Kevin.hammet, I added a note on units.

Comment: If I wanted to plot frequency spectrum of audio signals before and after some filtering, is `periodogram` the way to go, or I should use `fft`? It's just for debugging purposes and insight into what's going on with the signal.